# TextView width confusion

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm creating a detail view using the GridLayout and textviews.  My GridLayout will have about 6 rows and 2 columns.  On my first row, I have two textviews. The first (placard) has an background image which I'm centering text on top of it. My image is about 150 px wide. The second textview (material) can have anything from one word to 20 words.  I would like the text to wrap (up to 5 lines).

My problems is that the text in the second textview (material) is going off the screen. I have tried many different settings trying to get the width to adjust without success.  Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout 
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:background="@color/lemon"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowCount="6" >    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/placard"
        grid:layout_gravity="right"
        grid:layout_column="0"
        grid:layout_row="0"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/material"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        grid:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How come you are defining 6 rows but only define elements for 1?

Comment: I wanted to resolve the issue with the first row before putting the time and effort into the additional rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link I found that explains how to solve this problem... Basically, when you are using the support version of GridLayout you need to specify your own namespace.

http://www.mentby.com/scott-olcott/gridlayout-text-clipping-using-support-library.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll keep it in mind if I ever try to use the GridLayout again.  I eventually resolved this issue using linear layouts to get the effect I wanted.